# merging two lists with similar key and concat values or concat values from single list

Tags: vb.net

I have two lists of strings both might not have same Key and value
list1

```
(0) = {[Str1, J44]}
(1) = {[Str2, J45]}
(2) = {[Str3, J46]}
```

list2

```
(0) = {[Str1, J47]}
(1) = {[Str2, J48]}
(2) = {[Str3, J49]}
(3) = {[Str4, J50]}
```

I want to concat or merge these as
mergedList

```
(0) = {[Str1, =J44+J47]}
(1) = {[Str2, =J45+J48]}
(2) = {[Str3, =J46+J49]}
(3) = {[Str4, =J50]}
```

**Second Option**
    I can get all these in single list as List1
    (0) = {[Str1, J44]}
    (1) = {[Str2, J45]}
    (2) = {[Str3, J46]}
    (3) = {[Str1, J47]}
    (4) = {[Str2, J48]}
    (5) = {[Str3, J49]}
    (6) = {[Str4, J50]}

I need the result same as above. For this I have done so far for second Option

```
Dim MergePavStr = (From kvps In List1 Group kvps By kvps.Key Into Group Select New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(Key, Group.Concat(Function(kvp) kvp.Value))).ToList()
```

But I cannot find the right way to concat.

**UPdate Solved**
I have achieved it by doing the following code. Hope this is also the solution since I am pretty new to vb.net

```
Dim MergePavStr = (From kvps In List1 Group kvps By kvps.Key Into Group Select New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(Key, String.Join("+", Group.Select(Function(p) p.Value).ToArray()))).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the key value pair lists (or dictionaries) with `.Concat` before grouping:

```
Dim result = List1.Concat(List2).GroupBy(Function(p) p.Key, Function(p) p.Value).
                            ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, Function(g) String.Concat(g))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what data structures you are using. Have you considered doing it the easy way?

```
Module Module1

    Sub MergeInto(dest As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)), src As Dictionary(Of String, String))
        For Each kvp In src
            If dest.ContainsKey(kvp.Key) Then
                dest(kvp.Key).Add(kvp.Value)
            Else
                dest.Add(kvp.Key, New List(Of String) From {kvp.Value})
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim x As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"Str1", "J44"}, {"Str2", "J45"}, {"Str3", "J46"}}
        Dim y As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"Str1", "J47"}, {"Str2", "J48"}, {"Str3", "J49"}, {"Str4", "J50"}}
        Dim z As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))

        MergeInto(z, x)
        MergeInto(z, y)

        Dim i = 0
        For Each kvp In z
            Console.WriteLine($"({i}) = {{[{kvp.Key}, ={String.Join("+", kvp.Value)}]}}")
            i += 1
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> (0) = {[Str1, =J44+J47]}
>   (1) = {[Str2, =J45+J48]}
>   (2) = {[Str3, =J46+J49]}
>   (3) = {[Str4, =J50]}

It would of course be tidier as an extension method and it needs a better name, which are left as an exercise for the reader.